# Regular Kernel Panics 10.11.3: com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I am experiencing new regular kernel panics on a Mid-2012 13” MacBook Pro. I’m not using any new 3rd party software and the hardware setup hasn’t changed. I tried uninstalling iShowU Audio Capture from Shinywhitebox.com. I had another panic, only this time, there was no log, so I reinstalled it.

In each case, the "kernel extensions in backtrace” is "com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(163.0)”. Last loaded and unloaded kexts have always been “com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme”. Could anyone who understand panic reports help me to shed light on this issue? Thanks for reading.

```
Sun Feb  7 22:14:18 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802d1f076b): "soclose: NOFDREF"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c:1263
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8038d6b970 : 0xffffff802ccdf792 
0xffffff8038d6b9f0 : 0xffffff802d1f076b 
0xffffff8038d6ba40 : 0xffffff802d217664 
0xffffff8038d6ba60 : 0xffffff7faf95f36c 
0xffffff8038d6bb50 : 0xffffff7faf95beed 
0xffffff8038d6bc80 : 0xffffff802d19600b 
0xffffff8038d6bcc0 : 0xffffff802d1f27bc 
0xffffff8038d6be30 : 0xffffff802d1cfcb6 
0xffffff8038d6be60 : 0xffffff802d1c9787 
0xffffff8038d6bf00 : 0xffffff802d1c95be 
0xffffff8038d6bf60 : 0xffffff802d22a731 
0xffffff8038d6bfb0 : 0xffffff802cdf0a36 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(163.0)[113F310F-1904-3F41-A206-1D275BF7A397]@0xffffff7faf95a000->0xffffff7faf961fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: socketfilterfw

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x000000002ca00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802cc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802cb00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4588931765960
last loaded kext at 1962940091218: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7faf964000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 2032878020322: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7faf964000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: My Passport 0748
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1

Wed Feb 10 09:10:47 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80065f076b): "soclose: NOFDREF"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c:1263
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8107e83970 : 0xffffff80060df792 
0xffffff8107e839f0 : 0xffffff80065f076b 
0xffffff8107e83a40 : 0xffffff8006617664 
0xffffff8107e83a60 : 0xffffff7f88cee36c 
0xffffff8107e83b50 : 0xffffff7f88ceaeed 
0xffffff8107e83c80 : 0xffffff800659600b 
0xffffff8107e83cc0 : 0xffffff80065f27bc 
0xffffff8107e83e30 : 0xffffff80065cfcb6 
0xffffff8107e83e60 : 0xffffff80065c9787 
0xffffff8107e83f00 : 0xffffff80065c95be 
0xffffff8107e83f60 : 0xffffff800662a731 
0xffffff8107e83fb0 : 0xffffff80061f0a36 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(163.0)[113F310F-1904-3F41-A206-1D275BF7A397]@0xffffff7f88ce9000->0xffffff7f88cf0fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: socketfilterfw

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005f00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 37285454424088
last loaded kext at 4245648947402: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f88d06000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 4405539670619: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f88d06000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   90.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    3.7.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0C, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B54463531323634485A2D3147364D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: My Passport 0748
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the following discussion, unfortunately it seems that a kernel issue is somehow affecting several applications including Spotify.

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Mac/Kernel-Panic-for-my-Mac-when-using-Spotify/td-p/1218495/

In my case, I was unlucky as I had set Spotify to "open automatically at login" and I was getting a constant kernel panic. In order to solve that problem I did the following:

- Reboot your Mac in safe mode (hold SHIFT while booting)
- While in safe mode, your mac will be extremely slow. Don't worry.
- Disable "Open at Login" by right clicking on the Spotify icon.

Most recent versions seem to be much more stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It’s frustrating that there’s no permanent fix yet, but good to know we’re not alone and that Apple are aware of it.

Comment: It really seems to be Spotify! Thanks for clearing that out!